# Making a multithreaded client method wait for a WCF service to finish before continuing with execution

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, web-services

**EDIT:**
Please note that everything works as intended when I have the client solution in debug mode. The solution with the service works fine in or out of debug mode.

---

I'm working on a file uploader that saves a user-uploaded .zip file to the server, unzips it, copies it to a bunch of different locations from there asynchronously (using web services), and then deletes the uploaded .zip file and unzipped files.

So:

1) upload and unzips the file

2) uses **QueueUserWorkItem(MethodName)** and redirects the user to a "thank you" page

3) **MethodName()** then makes a couple WCF web service calls that copy the unzipped folder to other places.

```
string copyToPaths = UploaderService.StartFolderUpload(_fileCategoryName, topDir);
UploaderService.CompleteFolderUpload(copyToPaths);
```

4) Deletes old files once service calls have completed and the files are no longer necessary (**issue here**)

So my issue is that the method that calls the WCF services doesn't wait for the service calls to complete before saying its done and deletes the files. It deletes the uploaded files and then the web service obviously cannot use those files to copy to other locations.

How can I make a method (that has been called with **QueueUserWorkItem** ) wait for web service calls to finish before moving on with its execution?

Comment: You should update your question title to be more related to your problem. Use your tags to say what technology etc your using

Comment: Your post suggests that deleting the files is done on the line below `QueueUserWorkItem(MethodName)`.  That will not work, as `QueueUserWorkItem` returns immediately. They should be at the end of MethodName.

Comment: No - the deleting is done at the end of the MethodName() method, not after the QueueUserWorkItem(MethodName) call.

Comment: Change the OperationContract of CompleteFolderUpload so it returns some value.  Then the client waits to get the response back from this service method before continuing.

Comment: I tried to attach a dummy boolean value to all of the service methods and I'm still having the same issue. Seems like that would make the client wait for the service to return before continuing though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this behaviour has nothing to do with the client side.  It's controlled by the OperationContract attribute on the service method.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void CompleteFolderUpload(string copyToPaths);
```

Is this what the second service method looks like?  If it is, then you must set IsOneWay to false (or just remove it) if you want clients to wait for this method to complete.  IsOneWay = true means that clients should not expect a response from the server, so they will almost always return before the method completes.

Comment: I tried adding this to all of my service methods, however I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: What did you add, exactly?  If the "IsOneWay" parameter is missing, then this is equivalent to "IsOneWay = false", which is what you want.  If the service operations are marked correctly, then perhaps the service method itself is asynchronous.  For instance, it might simply queue its work to execute on a worker thread and then return immediately.  Do you control the service code?

Comment: Yeah I control both service and client code. I specifically added [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)] to each method on the interface that the service inherits from.

Comment: Also - not sure if you saw my edit at the top? I'm 95% sure I need to modify something in the client code as when I debug the client solution (AKA make it work on a single thread) everything works fine.

Comment: In your description, does "MethodName" both call the service methods and delete the files?

Comment: Yes, the very last line is deleting the files after they have been processed by the service methods. Or at least that's how I want it to work and how it works in debug mode.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I'm at a loss then.  I'm fairly certain that you're barking up the wrong tree, however.  Your calls to the service methods are not returning before those operations complete.

Comment: What tree should I be barking up then? The problem is that the service methods ARE returning before they complete. Or at least the client is continuing to execute without waiting for them to return.

Comment: Well, you've declared your service methods as synchronous and you're executing the service calls and your delete call on the same thread, so it sounds like your problem is service-side.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider making your WCF service a [Duplex service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx). This way you can specify a callback on the client so you know when the service has finished. It also you to pass data back to your client e.g. Error information etc